# I want to get an attribute from the textarea that uses the onkeypress event

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code:

```
<div>
    <form name="comentario" id="<?php echo $id?>" action="funcion_enviar_comentario.php" method="post">
        <input hidden="hidden" type="text" id="inputid" name="inputid" value="<?php echo $id?>">
        <textarea  class=estilotextarea1 id="comentario<?php echo $id?>" onkeypress="process1(event,this)" name="<?php echo $id?>" placeholder="Introduce tu comentario aquí..."></textarea>
        <script>
            function process1(e) {
              //var ide= document.getElementById("comentario <?php echo $id?>").name;
              //var submit= document.getElementById("enviado<?php echo $id?>").
              var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
              if (code == 13) { 
                $('form#comentario<?php echo $id?>').submit();

               }
            }
        </script>
    </form>       
</div>
```

I want the function process1 to take the attribute name from the textarea that it is triggering the event(this code is inside a PHP while query) to store it in a variable  so I can use that variable to submit the form which id matches the variable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should detail the issue you have. That said, having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you can use something like this:

```
<div>
                <form name="comentario" id="1" action="funcion_enviar_comentario.php" method="post">
                <input hidden="hidden" type="text" id="inputid" name="inputid" value="1">
                <textarea  class=estilotextarea1 id="comentario1" onkeypress="process1(event,this.id)" name="1" placeholder="Introduce tu comentario aquí..."></textarea>

            </form>       
</div>

 <div>
                <form name="comentario" id="2" action="funcion_enviar_comentario.php" method="post">
                <input hidden="hidden" type="text" id="inputid" name="inputid" value="2">
                <textarea  class=estilotextarea1 id="comentario2" onkeypress="process1(event,this.id)" name="1" placeholder="Introduce tu comentario aquí..."></textarea>

            </form>       
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
  function process1(e,id) {

          var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
          if (code == 13) { 

                    alert('form #'+id);

           $('form #'+id).parent('form').submit();

            }
          }
```

So, process1, shouldn't be inside loop, you can easily get id, by passing it to function as parameter... DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/msgosoaL/1/

And, last line explanation - you can't submit textarea, so you need to target parent form...

Comment: The onkeypress(event,this.id) part of the code worked perfectly for me, thanks!